# C# - EF 6 Relationships Fluent API (1:1..0)

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, foreign-keys, ef-fluent-api

I'm having some trouble finding out the correct way to map my *Client/Person* classes in the EF 6.1.3.

```
    public class Client
    {
      public int ClientId { get; set; }
      public int PersonId { get; set; } // FK

      // Navigation Properties
      public virtual Person Person { get; set; }
    }

    public class Person
    {
      public int PersonId { get; set; }
    }
```

Here it is how it Works:

Client requires one Person,
Person has one optional client.

The FK is in the Client class but i can't do this relationship:

```
public class ClientMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<Client>
{
    public ClientMap()
    {
        // Primary Key
        HasKey(t => t.ClienteId);

        // Properties
        Property(t => t.ClientId).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity); // Auto-increment
        Property(t => t.PersonId).IsRequired(); // FK to Person

        // Relationships
        // Error here, HasForeignKey doesnt exists.
        HasRequired(t => t.Person).WithOptional().HasForeignKey(t => t.PersonId);

        // Table
        ToTable("Client");
    }
}
```

I've seen the MapKey method but I'm unsure of how it works because I read that it's only used when your FK property is not declared in the model, but in my scenario it is declared as the *PersonId* in the *Client* class.

The *Person* class will not have a navigaton property to *Client*, only *Client* to *Person*.

The question: How to map this correctly using Fluent API from the ClientMap class?

Any help would be much apprecited.

Comment: Have you tried adding a Client navigation property to Person and then doing HasRequired(t => t.Person).WithOptional(c => c.Client) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to implement **one** to **one optional** relation.

In this case EF expects that the optional entity has a foreign key that is also the primary key. It is the only way with EF.

If you want a separate FK, you have to implement a **one** to **many** relation and handle the uniqueness at business layer.

Please see [setup relation for 1 to 1 with entity framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29253814/setup-relation-for-1-to-1-with-entity-framework/29254330#29254330)

Comment: Looks like that one-to-one relationships where you can choose the FK is a feature only avaible in EF 7. In EF 6 and below you must use the tables PKs as FKs in these relations. The _WithMany()_ solutiuon might work. Thanks.